# finding the location of text in a UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

Is it possible to find the exact location of text within a UILabel? (for example, if the label  can be a varying width but the text can be right aligned or left alight)

Possible? not possible? not worth the effort?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to detect the state of the label's current text alignment, you can use this:

```
if (myLabel.textAlignment == UITextAlignmentLeft) {
    //do something for left alignment
}else if (myLabel.textAlignment == UITextAlignmentRight){
    //do something for right alignment
}else{
    //do something for center alignment
}
```

And to make the label "tappable" you can do this by enabling user interaction on the label and adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:)];
[tap setDelegate:self];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Comment: i'd like to make the text tappable . . .

Comment: its not simply making the label tappable . . . its making only the portion containing text tappable.

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser You should have included all this in your original post... to do that you have to receive UITouch events within the labels view, get the touch location as a GCPoint, and compare that point to rectangles you can specify for different locations within the label.